# PHP forced download cuts off before completing

Tags: php, video, header, jwplayer

I have a link to download a video which is hosted in our JW Videos Platform. The link is secure (it only works for a set number of minutes) and it works fine.

```
http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/QPSxxAok-9zxxLY4Q.mp4?exp=1428027050&sig=602c32cd61617b1ddafd3f47857fcc44
```

The only issue is that when I click on it, the video loads in the browser by default. Also if I right click on the link and choose "Save Link As", even though it works, the filename is a code instead of the name of the video.

I found a solution to this by changing the link to a form button and having the form call a separate PHP page.

This is the form I use instead of the link ($videoURL is set to the link I wrote above).

```
<form action="testfile.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="<?php echo $videoURL ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo 'My_Video' ?>" />
<button>Download</button>
</form>
```

This is the code I have in testfile.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/mp4');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$_POST['file'].'.mp4');
readfile($_POST['link']);
?>
```

The problem is that, even though the download begins automatically and it shows the filename I selected, the download cuts off before the file has finished downloading.

Any ideas as to what may be going wrong here? Why is the download only working for a short while and not for the whole video?

Comment: How long does it take to download the video? You may be exceeding PHP's execution time limit.

Comment: Some videos are 1 GB. I downloaded one successfully in 30 minutes using the link. But with the form button, the download cuts off.

Comment: Are these videos on your own JW Platform account?

Comment: Because, if they are, you can download the originals from your own account, without having to use PHP to do it.

Comment: This is a script that will be added to our website so that users who purchase the video can download it from a provided link, which will only be valid for a certain amount of time.

Comment: If you look at your account, you will see that the links to download the originals do not have timestamps, but once the urls are accessed, the timestamp / expiration is added. You should be able to use these URLs for your script.